# create doesn't exist on Actionsheet Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I have problem with actionsheet in ionic 2..

This is the code

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ActionSheet} from 'ionic-native';

@Page({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
constructor(public nav: NavController) {}

signIn(){
let sheet = ActionSheet.create({
title : 'Sign In as',
buttons : [
{
text:'Partner',
handler : () =>{
console.log('Cancel clicked');
}
},{
text:'Member',
handler : ()=>{
console.log('Cancel clicked');
}
},{
text:'Cancel',
role:'cancel',
handler : ()=>{
console.log('Cancel clicked');
}
}
]
});
this.nav.present(sheet);
}
}
```

when i try to ionic serve there are errors

TypeScript error: D:/xampp/htdocs/payogo/android_2/Payogo/app/pages/home/home.ts(41,33): Error TS2339: Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof ActionSheet'.

Please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

isnt is `ActionSheet.show()`

See documentation: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet